# Understanding Scala default argument message

Tags: scala, methods

I am playing around with some Scala code and have met with an error message I don't quite follow. Below is my code

```
val ignoredIds = Array("one", "two", "three")


def csNotify(x : Any): String = {

  case org: String if !ignoredIds.contains(x) =>
    println( s" $x  should not be here")
    "one"
  case org : String if ignoredIds.contains(x) =>
    println(s"$x should be here")
    "two"
}

csNotify("four")
```

The console output is that I am the arguments for a default function must be known. The error point appears to be pointing at the " String = ". Why would this be the case ? The function should check the two cases and return a string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your case is not finding the match against which it can check your block , and you have missed the match block:

```
val ignoredIds = Array("one", "two", "three")


def csNotify(x : Any): String =  x  match {

 case org: String if !ignoredIds.contains(x) =>
println( s" $x  should not be here")
"one"
 case org : String if ignoredIds.contains(x) =>
println(s"$x should be here")
"two"
}

csNotify("four")
```

So basically when you pass `x` in method , you have to give it for match as well.

Answer (score 3):

Amit Prasad's answer already shows how to fix it, but to explain the error message:

```
{

  case org: String if !ignoredIds.contains(x) =>
    println( s" $x  should not be here")
    "one"
  case org : String if ignoredIds.contains(x) =>
    println(s"$x should be here")
    "two"
}
```

on its own (without `... match` before it) is [a pattern-matching anonymous function](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/12/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-4-pattern-matching-anonymous-functions.html), which can only be used where the compiler knows the argument type from the context, i.e. the expected type must be either `PartialFunction[Something, SomethingElse]` or a single-abstract-method type (including `Something => SomethingElse`).

Here the expected type is `String`, which isn't either of those, so the compiler complains about not knowing what the argument type is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `match` keyword here to use cases. There might be some value for which you will be using pattern matching. So use the following code in your function:

```
x  match {
  case org: String if !ignoredIds.contains(x) => ???
  case org : String if ignoredIds.contains(x) => ???
}
```

Also, you should consider adding one more case which is default. As you know the parameter `x` of your function `def csNotify(x: Any): String` is of type any. So anything other than `String` can also be passed here like `Int` or `Boolean` or any custom type. In that case, the code will break with match error.

There will also be a compiler warning saying `match is not exhaustive` as the current code does not handle all possible values for type `Any` of parameter `x`.

But if you add one default case in your pattern matching, all the cases which are not handled by the first two cases (unexpected type or values) will go to the default case. In this way the code will be more robust:

```
def csNotify(x : Any): String =  x  match {
  case org: String if !ignoredIds.contains(org) => ???
  case org : String if ignoredIds.contains(org) => ???
  case org => s"unwanted value: $org" // or any default value
}
```

Note: Kindly replace `???` with your intended code. :)